# windows 7 registry values suddenly not parsing %variables%?

Tags: windows-7, environment-variables

This may be a false-positive, I'm in testmode.

The problem I noticed was my touchpad wasn't working. As a fluke, I fixed it by replacing the %relative%\path with an absolute path.

Thought my scrollpad was misbehaving, looked into registry, ensured I hadn't disabled **SynTPEnh** @

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

Changed
%ProgramFiles%\Synaptics\SynTP\SynTPEnh.exe
to
"C:\program files\Synaptics\SynTP\SynTPEnh.exe"

logged off and on... seems ok.

ran **set**
**ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files**

environment variables is ok...

anyone noticed this? is this *normal*?

thanks in advance

Comment: I assume you're talking about cmd prompt? When using paths, make sure that when you use paths with "s p a c e s", that you use the quotation marks or else set ProgramFiles becomes C:\Program; stopping at the space.

Answer (score 0):

> It depends on the type of the Registry value. REG_EXPAND_SZ values
>   will have the environment variables expanded when read, REG_SZ values
>   will not. Either type may appear under the ...\Run\ subkey. It's
>   clearly a mistake to use an environment variable in REG_SZ data, if
>   the application reading it expects to get the expanded version.  Paths
>   with environment variables are not relative paths.  share | edit 
>   answered Dec 27 '16 at 0:48    kreemoweet  3,001 10 12 So how does the
>   author specifically solve their problem – Ramhound  Dec 27 '16 at 3:06
>   help  add a comment |

Quite right, quick glance with regjump (rj HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run)

[image]

It's working now, so I think it was not reg_expand_sz before?

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the type of the Registry value. REG_EXPAND_SZ values will have the environment variables expanded when read, REG_SZ values will not. Either type may appear under the ...\Run\ subkey. It's clearly a mistake to use an environment variable in REG_SZ data, if the application reading it expects to get the expanded version.

Paths with environment variables are not relative paths.

Comment: So how does the author specifically solve their problem